# Capturing menubutton event on PhoneGap 5.x

Tags: android, cordova, events

Before this, I could capture hardware menu button by menubutton event, just like this:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", function(){
    alert('MENU BUTTON PRESSED');
}, false);
```

But it doesn't work on v5.5.0 & v5.4.0  & v5.0.0 (Possible other 5.x.x versions too)

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8921

Probably it will be fixed in the new cordova version

Comment: Thanks Del, After about 24 hours of searching and testing, I just found that page, tested that solution and worked! I logged in to SO to link that page here for others and I saw that you did that just now!! Anyway, thanks again, I'll accept this :)